# Oracle SQL - return record only if colB is the same for all of colA

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like the following ( there is of course other data in the table):

```
Col A          Col B
1              Red
1              Red
2              Blue
2              Green
3              Black
```

I am trying to return a value for Col A only when ALL the Col B values match, otherwise return null.

This will be used as part of another sql statement that will be passing the Col A value, ie 
Select * from Table where Col A = 1

I need to return the value in Col B.  The correct result in the above table would be Red,Black

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45f6d/18)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t( id number, color varchar2(20));

insert into t values(1,'RED');
insert into t values(1,'RED');
insert into t values(2,'BLUE');
insert into t values(2,'GREEN');
insert into t values(3,'BLACK');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select color from t where id in (
select id
from t
group by id having min(color) = max(color) )
group by color
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45f6d/18/0)**:
    | COLOR |
    |-------|
    |   RED |
    | BLACK |

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the *values* in A (rather than each row), then use `group by`:

```
select a
from table t
group by a
having min(b) = max(b);
```

Note:  this ignores `NULL` values.  If you want to treat them as an additional value, then add another condition:

```
select a
from table t
group by a
having min(b) = max(b) and count(*) = count(b);
```

It is also tempting to use `count(distinct)`.  In general, though, `count(distinct)` requires more processing effort than a `min()` and a `max()`.

Comment: I actually just want the values in B.  So, in my table above the valid values for B are :  Red and Black

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement.

```
select cola,
case when max(colb) = min(colb) and count(*) = count(colb) then max(colb)
end as colb
from tablename
group by cola
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45f6d/14)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t( id number, color varchar2(20));

insert into t values(1,'RED');
insert into t values(1,'RED');
insert into t values(2,'BLUE');
insert into t values(2,'GREEN');
insert into t values(3,'BLACK');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id
from t
group by id having min(color) = max(color)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45f6d/14/0)**:
    | ID |
    |----|
    |  1 |
    |  3 |

hope this is what you were looking for.. :)

Comment: Almost, except I need it to return Red, Black, not 1,3

Comment: @flyingpie, please check below answer from me and let me know if this is what you seek.